# How do I change comma to a colon in in-text reference?

Tags: citing, punctuation, natbib

In my preamble I am using:

```
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

When I make a `\cite` reference the output is for example:

> (Lovell, 1972, p.133)

What would I need to change in order to have the comma after the year appear as a colon? Such as:

> (Lovell, 1972: p.133)

Answer (score 6):

Use `\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}`. See section 2.9 of the `natbib` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep[p.~99]{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Immediate help, thank you very much.