# Overwriting harvard style

Tags: citing, harvard-style

It's a bit tricky as I can use the standard Harvard style which is `(Author YYYY)`. The "german" (having no idea how it's called) way is to build show the page as well. M

More accurate: `(Author, YYYY: PP)`, where `PP` is the page. Several authors will be simply seperated by a comma. Beside that I need something similar to `Cf.` which is `vgl.`.

I am pretty new to LateX but I am more or less familiar with programming. So I'd expect a way to overwrite the default way of citing by something like this: `\cite{src}{PP}` which ends up in `(Author, YYYY: PP)` and something like `\citevgl{src}{PP}` which should result this: `(vgl. Author, YYYY: PP)`.

Configuration:

```
\LoadClass[10pt,twoside,b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

If I miss posting information please let me know.

As already commented below I can do it like this:
`\cite[vgl.][44]{document}` which results in `(Author YYYY, 44)`. So I just need to replace the comma by a colon. Not sure how to do that yet tho. Another issue is that the entries in my bibliography are affected by the `bibliographystyle{agsm}`.

Before that I was using `bibliographystyle{plain}`, but using this config the harvard style does not apply as above `(Author YYYY: PP)`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure what style/bibliography setup you are using. But you could try something like `\cite[PP]{entrykey}` or `\cite[vgl.][PP]{entrykey}` and it will probably work.

Comment: Read an introduction to LaTeX. Your programming knowledge is pretty much useless right now.

Comment: Whether and how it is possible to display citations as you wish with just `\cite` or a similar command strongly depends on the bibliography and citation package you use. With `biblatex` for example `\autocite[vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}` (or `\parencite[vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}`) should give you almost what you want subject to some small and fairly straightforward modifications. With other packages that might be slightly more difficult. Please tell us which package and bibliography style you use in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/).

Comment: @moewe Out of curiosity, doesn't `natbib` have pre and postnotes? Which setup would not afford them?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, `natbib` has them. `cite` and the standard implementation don't support pre-notes in that form. Neither do `apacite` and `harvard.sty`. But there are some packages that use a slightly different command format to allow for pre-notes (I forget which one it was).

Comment: It is kind of expected that the bibliography output would be affected by changing from `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` (of the `harvard` package). Since you are using `natbib` anyway, you could try with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` instead, if you like that better. For the question about the colon, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85901/35864.